# azureml-sdk ignores the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable

Tags: python, azure, ssl, azure-machine-learning-service, certifi

I'm using **`azureml-sdk`** behind a corporate's proxy and therefore forced to manually add the proxy's certificate to the list of trusted hosts. It works fine by manually append the server certificate to the file "**`cert_ca.pem`**" of the package certifi.

As mentioned in the documentation of `python-requests`, this should also be possible by setting the environment variable "**`REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`**" to a specific file. However, the environment variable seems to be ignored by **`azureml-sdk`**. Is this the correct behavior? Or how is it possible to specify an own "`pem`" file?

Answer (score 0):

The correct environment variable is `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` - note the plural.

Comment: Oh it was a typo. I mean "**`REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`**" of course. Thank you for the comment @Architect Jamie

Comment: @0xFF how dependent are you on certifi?  I wondered whether it's conflicting with/overriding the standard behavior.

Comment: I'm not depending at all. Appending the proxy's certificate to the certifi 'pem' file was the only solution i found. Without the modified pem file, a connection to azure is not possible. Do you know other solutions?

Comment: Did we get the answer for this query? How this is solved? Facing same issue..